# Вчера уже это сделал(,) и завтра приду к тебе с фотоотчётом

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Вчера уже это сделал(,) и завтра приду к тебе с фотоотчётом.

Comment: Леопольд, ***с** фотоотчётом*, наверно?

Comment: Леопольд! Если  ***с***, то тогда уж везде. И в шапке тоже.

Comment: М-м... "Спасибо" дожидаюсь — неимоверно...

Comment: I am grateful to your for your eagle eyes and corrections.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр   (1) … и завтра приду к тебе ФОТООТЧЕТОМ. Я сначала думала, что предлог специально пропущен: приду (как?) фотоотчетом. Каково сказано!  (2) О наших редакторах с орлиным зрением (есть у нас такие), и я их немножко боюсь.  Вспоминается эпизод из книги (фантастика):  Юстик заметался: – Это абсолютно секретные данные! Я давал клятву о неразглашении на клетке Грифа Секретности! – Да, птичка серьёзная. Клювом так долбанёт – и не встанешь! – согласилась Настасья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не будет беды, если запятую поставить, но лучше тире.

Comment: А почему тире лучше?  Вы по слуху определяете или как-то еще? Интуиция?  Просто интересно (правил не нужно).

Comment: Наверное, из-за быстрой смены событий.

Answer (score 1):

Тире это мостик из прошлого в будущее в данном случае. Тут знак пунктуации для обогащения фразы дополнительным смыслом. Можно и не употреблять, конечно, знаки. Просто союза достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. А в грамматике  и правилах все не так. Знак надо ставить, но иногда не надо ставить. Запятая  — основной знак, но допускается замена тире в некоторых случаях. Целая философия))  Посмотрела вас в Стихи.ру  У вас много читателей.  Как-нибудь загляну. Спасибо.   Тире здсь действительно можно поставить. Голос от меня.